# Trying to create tables getting error

Tags: mysql, syntax

I can not find the syntax error:

```
Drop Table if Exists Classes;
Drop Table if Exists Grades;
Drop Table if Exists Faculty;
Drop Table if Exists Students;

CREATE TABLE Faculty (StaffID INTEGER( 11 ),
StaffFirstName VARCHAR( 50 ),
StaffLastName VARCHAR( 50 ),
StaffPhone VARCHAR, CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (StaffID) ) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE Students (
  StudentID INTEGER( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
   StudentFirstName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
   StudentLastName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
   StudentPhone VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
  ) ENGINE = innodb ;

 CREATE TABLE Classes (
  ClassID VARCHAR NOT NULL ,
  ClassName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (ClassID)
) ENGINE = innodb ;

 CREATE TABLE Grades (
 StaffID INTEGER( 11 ) NOT NULL ,  
 StudentID INTEGER( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 ClassID VARCHAR (11)NOT NULL ,
   Grade VARCHAR( 2 ),  
   CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, StudentID, ClassID),
 FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) references Faculty(StaffID),
 FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) references Students(StudentID),
 FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) references Classes(ClassID)
 ) ENGINE = innodb ;'
```

I have tried taking out spaces and commas and adding some I just can't find the spot.  This is the error:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (StaffID INTEGER( 11 ),
StaffFirstName VARCHAR( 50 ),
StaffLastName VARCHAR( 50 ),
StaffPhone VARCHAR, CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (StaffID) ) ENGINE = innodb;
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (StaffID) ) ENGINE = innodb' at line 4

Comment: Shouldn't you have a length for your StaffPhone VARCHAR column, e.g. VARCHAR(11) ?

Comment: It is not required, I actually took out my NOT NULL indicators

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with MySql, but is it necessary to add a length to an Integer column? You are saying that the first column is of type

> Integer (11)

Comment: It is not always necessary but to match an already existing table I need to define the same values, I actually finally got it to work, and I have no idea what I did, I just kept deleting spaces in case there were carriage returns or tabs and I defined values for all the VARCHAR types...